# Simple react-spring component not working in gatsby - Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-spring

Trying out react-spring, using a simple tutorial. However, it's not working for me. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Spring } from "react-spring"
export default class Box extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Spring
        from={{ opacity: 0, marginTop: -1000 }}
        to={{ opacity: 1, marginTop: 0 }}
      >
        {props => (
          <div style={props}>
            <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
            <p>Now go build something great.</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </Spring>
    )
  }
}
```

and here's the error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Box`.

I'm using react-spring in gatsby's default starter, and am simply importing my Box component like so:

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Box from "../components/box"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Box />
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: According to the docs it should be `import {Spring} from 'react-spring/renderprops'` ?

Comment: this fixed it ... is this fairly new? the tutorial I have been using (any many others I had a look at) hadn't updated this. thanks a lot! If you submit this, I'll accept it as the answer :)

Comment: The changelog says that in version 9.0 they changed how to import things. https://react-spring.io/changelog and `import { Spring, useSpring } from 'react-spring'` should work. I'm facing the same issue like you and I want to use a new to import that Spring module, but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The changelog says that in version 9.0 they changed how to [import things](https://react-spring.io/changelog) and `import { Spring, useSpring } from 'react-spring'` should work and should be used.

[I found on their GitHub issues](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/781#issuecomment-626193500) the solution that worked for me.

Put:
`'^react-spring$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-spring/web.cjs',`
in `jest.config.js`

In my case that was a submodule in monorepo so I had to jump up two directories to reach that library:
`'^react-spring$': '<rootDir>/../../node_modules/react-spring/web.cjs'`